# Spring Data JPA. Update entity wihtout using id

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have `Flat` entity. I need to update a lot of rows in relevant table, but I don't know ids of updated rows. I know that there are some ways of doing it:

1. Select all flats by unique parameter (not @Id), update persisted entity and then save it. 
   I don't want use it, because I have to get from database a lot of entities, when I really don't need it.
2. Create update method in JpaRepository with @Modifying and @Query annotations like `Update Flat f SET ..fields... WHERE f.unique_field=?1`  But in my case `Flat` entity contains 20+ fields, so my method will have 20+ parameters that is not very beatifull.

Is there another way to update entities without knowing id and select queries?

I hope that there is something that looks like 2nd way but with entity as parameter of update instead of plenty fields.

For example

```
@Modifying
@Query("Update Flat f where f.unique_field=?1)
Flat updateFlatByUniqueField(Flat flat, Long uniqueField)
```

Comment: Actually, first approach does not sound that bad at all. E.g. you could select all entities by that unique parameter. You'd get a list of entities which fields you can update. Then you can just batch save that modified list. That should be more efficient than executing update statement one by one. But your case is kind of broad since I don't know how many records you have to update. Maybe it's a candidate for batch processing job. Who knows.

Comment: It's expected tens of thousands updates in one transaction, but it can grows. It's not very big count for Oracle, but I want to avoid executing select and saving a lot of objects in memory only because I need @Id field. So I decide to try find more efficient way of solving this problem

Comment: That's clearly a batch job. Try Spring Batch. Do not expect it can end up very fast.